# Azure Recovery Services - Backup not running automatically

Tags: azure, backup

I configured Windows Azure Backup on my VM hosted on Azure. I did manage to create and upload a certificate following this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/171fe77a-8686-4dd1-a45a-b44df729b40b) and this [tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/recovery-services/configure-a-backup-vault/).

I downloaded the server agent to the VM and configured it, I then managed to perform a manual backup and it worked fine.

However I scheduled it to run every day at 3am using the wizard provided and it's not running. I check every day, and the last backup that is listed is the one I did manually. The dashboard in the Backup Server Agent shows it's scheduled, but it's not running.

I tried leaving the agent open overnight, and it didn't help.

Any insight on the situation will be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking my VM's event log, I figured out that the backup wasn't running as expected due to limited space in the HD. After I cleared some space it started running as expected.